# When re-indexing URL rewrite cache, configurable products get a URL key that looks like a MD5 hash

Tags: product, configurable-product, url, model, url-rewrite

I'm using Magento 1.8 alpha 1.
I wrote a shell script that changes some products (and calls save() afterwards).
Now, all the products that were altered have been assigned new URL keys that looks like MD5 hashes.

For example, `park.html` became `8c82c5200b256e05e3d48496f1c44528.html`.

**I tried truncating the `core_url_rewrite` table and re-indexing, but again, all those products still have meaningless URL keys.**

If it helps, the products happen to be configurable and visible in both catalog and search.

Comment: on a side-note: I highly recommend switching to the stable release of Magento 1.8. Alpha software generally has a lot of bugs in it.

Comment: Concur with @SanderMangel - you should update to the stable release, as the alpha was known to have URL index issues.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an alpha release. I would suggest, as would many others, to upgrade to a stable release now that it is out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the database? I would assume the url_key or url_path of the product is set to the hash. I can't find and occurence of `md5` inside the indexer code

Comment: You're right - the hash is in the key - but why?

Comment: I would say it was imported. I can't imagine, somewhere in magento core (but I didn't check) is the key set with a hash.